# is it safe to use a microwave that you burnt metal in?

Tags: microwave, burnt

i wasnt thinking and heated up tinfoil in the microwave, it full on caught on fire and burnt the top and sides of the microwave. is it still safe to use? it works but theres a burnt smell i'm working on getting out, but should i just get a new one?